# Somebody/someone gets/get *

Tags: grammatical-number, pronouns, verb-agreement

Which is correct: "Somebody gets punished" or "Somebody get punished?" I have the same question with respect to "Someone gets" and "Someone get." Is there a rule which applies to this kind of sentences?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The third person singular conjugation (simple present tense) of "to get" is "gets".  He/she/it "gets".  "Somebody" is third person singular, so it's "somebody gets...".  Similarly, it's "someone gets...".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Then I'm amazed so many people use 'get' instead of 'gets' (e.g. "There are few pleasures greater than watching somebody get yelled at")

Comment: I believe "somebody get yelled at" is a noun clause for "watching".  It answers "*what* is it a pleasure to watch?".  Here 'get' is not the simple present.  Compare "he *plays* ball" (simple present) to "I watch him *play* ball".

Comment: @Robert Smith: In your example "somebody" (someone/John..) is indeed subject of "get" but it is also complement of "watch".   If you replace *someone* with a personal pronoun you will say *There are few pleasures greater than watching **them** / **him**  get yelled at* (and **not** "they" or "he"). The complement form prevails, agreement is with the subject, not with the complement.


The rule is that when we use a verb after the verb *watch*, (& *see*, *let*, *hear*, *help*, *make*) the verb is not inflected (conjugated) and we must use the bare infinitive (-> without *to*).

Comment: Great, thanks both of you for your clarifications.